# Создание файла определенного размера с произвольными символами Linux (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

Есть такой вопрос.
Как создать конвейер на Ubuntu, чтобы решить следующую задачу: Создать файл 20мб, заполнить его произвольными символами, найти слова с буквой "D", сохранить эти слова в рузультат файла?

Понял глупость написанного мной. Переформулирую.
Необходимо создать текстовый файл и заполнить его случайными словами(набором английских букв длиной 6 символов) на 20мб. Это все пытаюсь сделать на C++, написав простую программу. Дальше просто из этого файла найти слова с буквой "D" и сохранить найденные слова в новый файл(это сделать с помощью конвейера).

В общем вопрос такой, как сделать генерацию случайных слов(представляю это как, генерацию случайных чисел и соотнести их буквам) и записать их в созданный этой же программой текстовый файл?

Comment: Какая-то невнятная формулировка задачи. Команда `dd if=/dev/urandom of=file.txt bs=1048576 count=20` создаст 20-мегабайтный файл со случайным содержимым, но что значит "найти слова"? "Слово" - это набор символов, ограниченных с двух сторон пробелом? Или два байта? Уточните сначала, что вам надо.

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: @Ilya символы и байты это немного разные штуки. тут скорее надо отфильтровать буквы в мусоре рандома

Comment: @Ilya, так скорее всего всё проще, на полученный файл: `strings <FILE> | grep D`

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите - по 6 букв:

```
char word[7] = {0};
for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    word[i] = ((rand()%2 == 0) ? 'a' : 'A') + rand()%26;
```

И пишете эти слова в нужном вам количестве.